# How do I find the Y intercept of a line using just the x intercept and the slope

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I had the x intercept and the slope of a graph, how to I get the y intercept of the graph mathematically. I remember learning how to do this but I forgot how to

Comment: Why have you added so many irrelevant tags? Answer: general form is $y = mx + c$ if you have the x intercept and slope, sub the x coord which is (a,0) into the general form with the slope as m. and solve for $c$.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at some introductory coordinate geometry videos.

Answer (score 1):

If the slope is $m$ and the x intercept is $a$, then the function is $y = m(x-a)$.
Sub in $x=0$ to get $m\cdot(-a)$, which will be the y intercept.